# Dynamic Height not working with position absolute

Tags: css, dynamic, background, position, absolute

I am trying to get the design of my homepage finished, however I am having some trouble getting the background color of a content div to flow passed a div.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="headerInfo">
            <div class="leftLocation">
                <p>golden, co</p>
            </div>
            <div class="rightInfo">
                <span class="text">
                    <a href="about.php">about us</a>
                    <a href="contact.php">contact</a>
                    <span class="phone">XXX-XXX-XXXX</span>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="rightPic">
                <img src="images/facebook.png" alt="facebook" title="facebook" />
                <img src="images/yelp.png" alt="yelp" title="yelp" />
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="homeHead">
            <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" />
            <img class="paintSplash" src="images/paintSplash.png" alt="paint" />
            <span id="nav">
                <a href="classes">classes</a>
                <a href="classes">calendar</a>
                <a href="classes">gallery</a>
                <a href="classes">FAQ</a>
                <a href="classes">private events</a>
                <a href="classes">large-scale</a>
            </span>
            <span id="word">
                ...Paint
            </span>
                <img src="images/homeSlide1.png" class="pic1" alt="pic1"/>
                <img src="images/homeSlide4.png" class="pic1" alt="pic2"/>
                <img src="images/homeSlide7.png" class="pic1" alt="pic3"/>

                <img src="images/homeSlide2.png" class="pic2" alt="pic4"/>
                <img src="images/homeSlide5.png" class="pic2" alt="pic5"/>
                <img src="images/homeSlide8.png" class="pic2" alt="pic6"/>

                <img src="images/homeSlide3.png" class="pic3" alt="pic7"/>
                <img src="images/homeSlide6.png" class="pic3" alt="pic8"/>
                <img src="images/homeSlide9.png" class="pic3" alt="pic9"/>
            <div id="step1">
                <span class="easy">Easy as</span>
                <span class="part">Sign Up</span>
                <span class="num">1.</span>
                <p style="padding-bottom:5px;">Pick your favorite class and <a href="#">REGISTER ONLINE</a>.</p>
                <p class="bottom"><a href="#">Classes</a> Starting at only $25!</p>
            </div>
            <div id="step2">
                <span class="part">Show Up</span>
                <span class="num">2.</span>
                <p style="padding-bottom:5px;">We supply everything! Check out the <a href="#">FAQ</a>.</p>
                <p class="bottom">Limited Seating, <a href="#">Register Now!</a></p>
            </div>
            <div id="step3">
                <span class="part2">Enjoy!</span>
                <span class="num2">3.</span>
                <img class="wine" src="images/wine.png" alt="wine" />
                <p style="padding-bottom:10px;">Sip your drink, paint, play &amp; have fun.</p>
                <p class="bottom">See our <a href="#">Gallery</a> for results!</p>
            </div>
        </div><!--End Header Info -->
        <div id="bodyInfo">
            <div id="left">
                <p>
                    <span class="bloodHeader">Welcome</span> to Art on the Brix where anyone can unleash their inner artist amidst friends, family and co-workers. Quickly <a href="#">Sign-Up</a> for a class or take your time to enjoy our website!
                </p>
                <p id="midLeft">
                    <span class="blueHeader">NO TALENT OR EXPERIENCE IS NECESSARY!</span>Colorful Variety of Themed Classes &#8226; Open Studio Times &#8226; Private Parties &#8226; Corporate Team-Builds &#8226; Charity Events
                </p>
                <p>
                    Our casual yet upscale studio is in the heaert of historic Golden, Colorado. Enjoy painting, crafts, wine or beer, music and fun surprises in our low-stress art classes. Our local artists guie all of the <a href="#">CLASSES</a> with easy-to-folow, step-by-step instruction on how to create the featured piece. The experience is playful and light-hearted encouraging you to just follow along or release inhibitions and go outside your lines. Create, taste and play!
                </p>
            </div>
            <div id="right">
            </div>
        </div><!-- End bodyInfo -->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
#content{
width:900px;
height:100%;
margin:0px auto;
background-color:#FFF;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px; /* future proofing */
-khtml-border-radius: 10px; /* for old Konqueror browsers */
}
/*Header Info*/
#headerInfo{
position: relative;
}
.leftLocation{
float:left;
font-family: HelveticaNeueStd;
font-size:14px;
color:#4d2c0d;
height:30px;
margin-top:10px;
}
.leftLocation p{
padding-right:5px;
}
.rightInfo{
position: relative;
float:right;
width:360px;
}
.rightInfo a{
color:#3397bf;
text-decoration: none;
font-size:14px;
font-family: HelveticaNeueStd;
padding-right:10px;
}
.rightInfo a:hover{
color:#e11b6b;
}
span.text{
position:absolute;
top:-7px;
}
span.phone{
font-family: Lavanderia;
font-size:30px;
color:#4d2c0d;
}
.rightPic{
position: absolute;
right:0px;
}
/*Home Head*/
#homeHead{
background-image:url('../images/homeHead.png');
width:900px;
height:573px;
position:relative;
clear: both;
}
.logo{
position: absolute;
top:-30px;
left:10px;
}
.paintSplash{
position: absolute;
left:350px;
top:-35px;
height:105px;
}
#nav{
position: absolute;
left:245px;
top:70px;
}
#nav a{
color:#FFF;
font-size: 16px;
font-family: HelveticaNeueStd;
padding-right:10px;
text-decoration: none;
}
#nav a:hover{
color:#e11b6b;
}
#word{
position: absolute;
top:90px;
left:235px;
padding:10px;
color:#3397bf;
font-family: Lavanderia;
font-size:35px;
}
#pic1{

}
.pic1{
position:absolute;
top:249px;
left:160px;
width:140px;
height:174px;
}
#pic2{
transform: rotate(7deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(7deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(7deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform: rotate(7deg); /* Opera */
-moz-transform: rotate(7deg); /* Firefox */
}
.pic2{
position:absolute;
top:263px;
left:424px;
width:102px;
height:150px;
transform: rotate(7deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(7deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(7deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform: rotate(7deg); /* Opera */
-moz-transform: rotate(7deg); /* Firefox */
}
#pic3{
transform: rotate(-13deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-13deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(-13deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform: rotate(-13deg); /* Opera */
-moz-transform: rotate(-13deg); /* Firefox */
}
.pic3{
position:absolute;
top:252px;
left:641px;
width:121px;
height:173px;
transform: rotate(-13deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-13deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(-13deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform: rotate(-13deg); /* Opera */
-moz-transform: rotate(-13deg); /* Firefox */
}
#step1{
position:absolute;
font-family: Helvetica;
top:500px;
left:100px;
width:200px;
height:60px;
padding:15px;
text-align: center;
background-color:#f0deba;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
        box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px; /* future proofing */
-khtml-border-radius: 10px; /* for old Konqueror browsers */
}
#step1 a{
color:#e11b6b;
}
.bottom{
font-family: HelveticaNeueStd-Italic;
color:#3397bf;
}
.bottom a{
color:#e11b6b;
}
.easy{
font-family: Helvetica;
font-size:14px;
position: absolute;
color:#FFF;
top:-25px;
left:-30px;
}
.num{
font-family: HelveticaNeueStd;
font-size:45px;
color:#FFF;
position: absolute;
top:-45px;
left:20px;
}
.part{
font-family: Lavanderia;
color:#FFF;
font-size:40px;
position: absolute;
top:-45px;
left:60px;
}
.num2{
font-family: HelveticaNeueStd;
font-size:45px;
color:#FFF;
position: absolute;
top:-45px;
left:60px;
}
.part2{
font-family: Lavanderia;
color:#FFF;
font-size:40px;
position: absolute;
top:-45px;
left:100px;
}
#step2{
position:absolute;
font-family: Helvetica;
top:500px;
left:345px;
width:200px;
height:60px;
padding:15px;
text-align: center;
background-color:#f0deba;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
        box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px; /* future proofing */
-khtml-border-radius: 10px; /* for old Konqueror browsers */
}
#step2 a{
color:#e11b6b;
}
#step3{
position:absolute;
font-family: Helvetica;
top:500px;
left:590px;
width:200px;
height:60px;
padding:10px;
padding-bottom:20px;
padding-left:50px;
text-align: center;
background-color:#f0deba;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
        box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px; /* future proofing */
-khtml-border-radius: 10px; /* for old Konqueror browsers */
}
#step3 a{
color:#e11b6b;
}
.wine{
position:absolute;
top:-30px;
left:5px;
}
/*bodyInfo*/
#holder{
width:900px;
height:573px;
}
#bodyInfo{
width:100%;
}
#left{
width:450px;
float:left;
}
#right{
width:450px;
float:left;
}
```

Everything is wrapped in the container and content div so I thought as I add content after the homeHead the white background would just expand down as usual... not the case it just stays there. (Look at screenshot) If anyone has an idea to fix this I would be grateful!

[image: Problem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably related to the `"left"` and `"right"` divs floating ***out*** of your `bodyInfo` div. You need to include another div with `style="clear: both;"` as the last block element inside your `bodyInfo` div.

See this for more layouts using floats: [CSS Design Patterns - Float and Clear](http://cssdesignpatterns.com/Chapter%2007%20-%20POSITIONING1/Float%20and%20Clear/example.html)

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/t53TY/) a generic mock-up of your situation on jsFiddle. If you remove the div with the `style="clear: both"`, the border around the `bodyInfo` div no longer wraps around the two floating divs.

```
<div id="bodyInfo">
    <div id="left">
        <p>
            <span class="bloodHeader">Welcome</span> to Art on the Brix where anyone can unleash their inner artist amidst friends, family and co-workers. Quickly <a href="#">Sign-Up</a> for a class or take your time to enjoy our website!
        </p>
        <p id="midLeft">
            <span class="blueHeader">NO TALENT OR EXPERIENCE IS NECESSARY!</span>Colorful Variety of Themed Classes &#8226; Open Studio Times &#8226; Private Parties &#8226; Corporate Team-Builds &#8226; Charity Events
        </p>
        <p>
           Our casual yet upscale studio is in the heaert of historic Golden, Colorado. Enjoy painting, crafts, wine or beer, music and fun surprises in our low-stress art classes. Our local artists guie all of the <a href="#">CLASSES</a> with easy-to-folow, step-by-step instruction on how to create the featured piece. The experience is playful and light-hearted encouraging you to just follow along or release inhibitions and go outside your lines. Create, taste and play!
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="right"></div>
    <div sytle="clear: both;"></div>
</div><!-- End bodyInfo -->
```

Comment: ... I thought I tried this yesterday. But taking the rest of the day off helped clear my brain, haha. Clearing the div doesn't continue the white background, but hey, it's easy enough to just add a white background to the bodyInfo div.

Answer (score 0):

[Absolutely positioned elements do not expand their parents as they grow](http://jsbin.com/amahih/1/edit). The positioning of your content container should be static or relative.

[Here's some info for you on document flow](http://www.rainbodesign.com/pub/css/css-positioning-2.html); this is an important concept to understand.

Comment: That's nice to know, thank you! But what is the fix for it if you need "a" to grow with "b" in your case.

Comment: b's `position` should be `static` (which is default) or `relative`.

Comment: That doesn't help me though... The design I have to follow calls for a lot of things to be position absolute.

Comment: The different position values have purposes, and your design is expecting `position: absolute` to do something contrary to its purpose. Why is your design making implementation decisions anyway?

Comment: ... Then please tell me what I am supposed to be using instead of absolute.

Comment: I have. You should use `position: static` (since it is default you can just remove the absolute property) or `position: relative`. You can absolutely position other elements whose size will not change, but for dynamic content, unless you want it to appear inside a fixed-size box with a scrollbar, you should use margins or relative positioning to put it where you want. edit: added some reading material for you to my answer.